# In what sense is Bass-Serre theory the one-dimensional version of orbifold theory

Tags: geometric-group-theory, trees, orbifolds

The Wikipedia article on Bass-Serre theory claims that graphs of groups (in the context of Bass-Serre theory) "can be viewed as one dimensional versions of orbifolds." I hazily see a connection between a graph of groups and the notion of an orbifold, but I have no concrete sense of what the connection is nor how it is a 1 dimensional analogue. This is my first post on mathoverflow as a graduate student so apologies if my question is ill-posed or too basic.

Comment: Welcome to MO! (And more characters.)

Comment: Lol @ (and more characters.)

Comment: One way to think about graphs of groups is as quotients of graphs where you "remember" the stabilizers of the vertices and edges in case the action is not free, similar to how orbifolds are locally quotients of manifolds by finite groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A graph is a $1$-dimensional manifold with singularities and a graph of groups is, roughly, a $1$-dimensional orbifold with singularities. Every graph of groups has a [Bass-Serre covering tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass%E2%80%93Serre_theory#Bass%E2%80%93Serre_covering_trees) which is its universal cover as an orbifold, and it can be written as the quotient of this tree by its fundamental group $\pi_1$. This is exactly analogous to presenting an orbifold as a quotient of a manifold by a group action (when such a presentation exists).

Essentially the only example I understand in any detail is the graph of groups given by a copy of $C_2$ attached to a copy of $C_3$ by an edge, which, thought of as an orbifold, is the quotient of a certain tree (which I think is pictured [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane)) in the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}$ by the action of the [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) $C_2 \ast C_3 \cong PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. You can see some pictures of this orbifold and some of its finite covers (corresponding to finite index subgroups of the modular group) in [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/drawing-subgroups-of-the-modular-group/).